# How to configure on premise azure devops to fail on liquibase script error

Tags: azure-devops, liquibase

I have liquibase in a release pipeline and sometime there is an error in a script but the release still passes and doesnt warn or tell that it failed, sometime we find out days after the release is done.

my search skill is failing me, I can't seem to find a way to stop a release or give some kind of a warning that a liquibase error was there

Answer (score 0):

You can check the error in two ways.

1. As liquibase is a command line tool, you can check the console logs to find the error.
2. You can check the status code returned using
   `echo $?`